# How to batch decompress files with gunzip and keep originals?

Tags: linux, gunzip

I have several txt.gz files in a directory that I would like to decompress all in one go to a bunch of .txt files without getting rid of the originals. BUT I don't want them in standard output - as would be accomplished with the -c option. Rather I want them as files in the same directory, just with file.txt type name (as might be done with gunzip -c file.txt.gz > file.txt). Might anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple for loop:

```
 for i in *.txt.gz; do zcat "$i" > "${i%.*}"; done
```

`zcat` is equivalent to `gunzip -c`, but shorter.

The variable `$i` takes the names of all `*.txt.gz` files in the current directory (one after the other). `${i%.*}` strips the extension (`.gz`) from the file's name.

**Note**: This is bash syntax.

Comment: Well, this wouldn't restore the saved mtime. If you wants that, instead allocate a temp directory and then copy the `.txt.gz` there and then decompress with `gzip -d` and then move the `.txt` back, repeat for each `.txt.gz` and then when done remove the temp directory.

Comment: @DanD.: Using `touch -r` is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) instead of gunzip, it will keep your original archive files.

<del>`7za e original.txt.gz`</del>

To decompress multiple files, see @mpy's answer.

---

**Update**

As per @Dennis's comment, wrap wildcard with double quotation mark, p7zip will extract all `.txt.gz` files.

```
7za e "*.txt.gz"
```

Comment: If you're already using 7-Zip, just do `7za e "*.txt.gz"`.

Comment: @Dennis, good to know that.